# Last One Month Data

Tags: db2

I have a file in the DB2 database which records customer transactions. On a daily basis I need to run a report to extract last 1 months transaction. I change the date range manually everyday as below.

**WHERE TRAN_DATE BETWEEN 20170114 AND 20170215;**

Is there a way to do the coding without amending the dats manually?

Comment: those dats are going to get you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below WHERE clause in your report query to get last one month data

```
WHERE TRAN_DATE > (CURRENT_DATE - 1 MONTH)
```